Legend is overlapping the axes labels
I'm plotting a chart using echarts4r and the legend is overlapping the axis y labels. Do you have any idea on how to avoid this?
Below is my code:
library(nycflights13)
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

n_bins <- 100 # binning
flights %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% 
  mutate(
    arr_delay = cut(arr_delay, n_bins),
    dep_delay = cut(dep_delay, n_bins)
  ) %>% 
  count(arr_delay, dep_delay) %>% 
  e_charts(dep_delay) %>% 
  e_heatmap(arr_delay, n) %>% 
  e_visual_map(n) %>% 
  e_title("Arrival delay vs. departure delay") %>% 
  e_axis_labels("Departure delay", "Arrival delay")


The answer here should get you what you want.

I've tried and it doesn't work in my case.

I did test it before I suggested it's use, I used e_grid(left = 150, right = 150) (right, also, because the x-axis label was cut off). If that doesn't work, try updating your echarts4r package.
